# What does "instagram" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, proper-nouns, neologisms

I'm talking about the name of the popular Internet photograph service. I guess the first part of the word (insta) means *instant*, but I couldn't figure out what it means when it's colligated with *gram*.

Comment: [-gram](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-gram).

Comment: I've always known _gram_ as a unit of weight till now...

Comment: Interesting -- but surely you've encountered words like _telegram_, _sonogram_, and the like before?

Comment: As _Turkish_ is my native language, I've encountered the Turkish of _telegram_ which is _telgraf_. Turkish has a lot of borrowed words but I have never encountered any one ending with _gram_. I guess my confusion comes for this reason.

Comment: I assumed that you were not a native English speaker; but I suppose that it wouldn't be common to encounter _telegram_ in English texts in this day and age.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comes from "Telegram".  The answer is on their [About](http://instagr.am/about/) page:

> When we were kids we loved playing around with cameras -- we loved how all the old Polaroid cameras marketed themselves as “instant” (something we take for granted today). We also felt that the snapshots people were taking were kind of like telegrams in that they got sent over the wire to others -- so we figured why not combine the two?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-gram